# pythonを用いて2次元配列から重複する配列を取り出す

Tags: python

2次元配列liから重複する配列数を指定することでその配列を取り出せず困っています。

```
li=[[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[5,6,7]]
```

例えば、配列[1,2,3]は3つ重複しており、o=3 を指定することで[1,2,3]が取り出せるようにしたいです。
また、o=2とすると[5,6,7],[2,3,4,5]が取り出せることを想定しております。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: それは、リストのリスト、であって、2次元配列ではありません。用語の問題ではなく、別物だということは意識した方が良いでしょう。

Answer (score 2):

回答

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> li=[[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[5,6,7]]
>>> o = 2
>>> c = Counter(tuple(x) for x in li)
>>> [list(k) for k,v in c.items() if v==o]
[[2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: データ処理演習の宿題に代わりに答えている気分になってきた。。。

Comment: 迅速な解答、心より感謝申し上げます。

Answer (score 2):

カウントするのにリストでは都合が悪いため、一旦タプルにしてみました。
重複なしのデータはset()を使っています。

`li=[[1,2,3],[5,6,7],[2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[7,8,9],[2,3,4,5],[1,2,3],[5,6,7]]

tp = map(tuple, li)

tp`

> [(1, 2, 3),
>       (5, 6, 7),
>       (2, 3, 4, 5),
>       (1, 2, 3),
>       (7, 8, 9),
>       (2, 3, 4, 5),
>       (1, 2, 3),
>       (5, 6, 7)]

`pattern = tuple(set(tp))

pattern`

> ((2, 3, 4, 5), (5, 6, 7), (7, 8, 9), (1, 2, 3))

`qty = map(lambda x: tp.count(x), pattern)

qty`

> [2, 2, 1, 3]

`data = zip(qty, pattern)

data`

> [(2, (2, 3, 4, 5)), (2, (5, 6, 7)), (1, (7, 8, 9)), (3, (1, 2, 3))]

`o = lambda num: map(lambda y: list(y[1]), filter(lambda x: x[0] == num, data))

o(3)`

> [[1, 2, 3]]

`o(2)`

> [[2, 3, 4, 5], [5, 6, 7]]

Comment: 丁寧に解説していただきありがとうございます。参考になりました。